# Adjust the last element in the view (list view)

Tags: android, listview

I want to adjust a list to the last item on the screen.

[image]

[image]

I have a listview with a typical custom adapter. I've tried *setSelectionFromTop (int position, int y)*  but do not know the height of each item. Can you help? Thanks :)

Comment: The question not seems to be clear enough? `I want to set a list to the last item`. Actually what you supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, I want to adjust the last element in the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `listview.smoothScrollToPosition(lastposition)` :

> Smoothly scroll to the specified adapter position. The view will
>   scroll such that the indicated position is displayed.

or simple `setSelection(lastposition)` which not has nice scrolling animation.

But sometime in `ListView`, there is a bug make `ListView` not autoscroll ([Issue 10552](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10552)). So you must do this workaround. Try to first `setSelection` to position around your desire position and after `smoothScroll`

```
public static void scrollToTopListView(ListView list) {


            list.setSelection(15); // 
            list.smoothScrollToPosition(0);


    }
```